# Facebook. Graph API Explorer. Unsupported get request

Tags: facebook

I want to get information about the user.

436200186744638?fields=id,name,education,birthday

but i have error:

```
    {
"error": {
"message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '436200186744638' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
"type": "GraphMethodException",
"code": 100
"fbtrace_id": "DXx4cTKh7aM"
  }
}
```

ID is correct

Comment: The accesstoken can not see it. Use `/me?fields=id,name,education,birthday` and the access token from that user

Comment: How do I get a user's token?

Comment: I want to get information from someone else's profile. /me - is information about my profile.

Comment: You can only get information from people that logged in to your app. And if they have you have an access token for them